android chrome browser proxy setting
does android chrome browser support --proxy-pac-url command arguments ? can i set a remote server pac file url ?
reference offial document:
chromium network setting

--proxy-pac-url=

This tells Chrome to use the PAC file at the specified URL.
For example,
--proxy-pac-url="http://wpad/windows.pac"
will tell Chrome to resolve proxy information for URL requests using the windows.pac file.
question is:
i am not sure this is suitable for android chrome,is that true ? for android chrome
